# Finding a bijection from $\{1,2,...,nm\}$ to $X \times Y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that for two finite sets $X,Y$, where $|X|=n$, $|Y|=m$, $|X||Y|=|X \times Y|$. I know that there exists bijections $f:\{1,2,...,n\} \rightarrow X$ and $g:\{1,2,...,m\} \rightarrow Y$ and I'm trying to find a bijection $h:\{1,2,...,nm\} \rightarrow X \times Y$. I know that this is equivalent to showing there exists a bijection $k: X \times Y \rightarrow \{1,2,...,nm\}$. One such bijection that seemingly works is $k(x_i,y_j) = (i-1)m + j$, where $1 \leq i \leq n$ and $1 \leq j \leq m$. I've tried to prove the injectivity and surjectivity of this function but to no avail:

Injecivity: Suppose $k(x_a,y_b) = k(x_c,y_d)$ for $x_a, x_c \in X$ and $y_b, y_d \in Y$. This gives $(a-1)m + b = (c-1)m + d$ but I've not been able to show that $a = c, b = d$ from here.

Surjectivity: Suppose $z \in \{1,2,...,nm\}$ then $\exists i,j$ s.t. $ z = (i-1)m + j$ for some $i,j$ satisfying $1 \leq i \leq n$ and $1 \leq j \leq m$. Now, since $X, Y$ can be written as $X = \{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$, $Y = \{y_1,y_2,...,y_m\}$ and  $X \times Y  = \{(x,y) | x \in X \wedge y \in Y\}$ then we can say $\exists(x_i, y_j) \in X \times Y$ and by the definition of $k$ we have $k((x_i, y_j)) = (i-1)m + j$. But I'm not sure if this all watertight since I've assumed that $z$ can be written in the desired form.

Comment: Hint: If $k(x_i,y_j)=(i-1)m+j$, is there any constraint on $j$?

Comment: Hint: Have you heard of the division algorithm?

Comment: Yes, the constraint on $j$ would be $0 \leq j \leq m$ but would that then imply $1 \leq i - 1 \leq n+1$? I'm not sure exactly how to proceed.

Comment: No, both $i$ and $j$ are greater than $0$

Comment: Ok, how exactly would that then allow us to deduce that $i,j$ are appropriately constrained for there to exist $(x_i, y_j)$ s.t. $k(x_i, y_j) = (i-1)m+j$?

Comment: @Hai indeed, your surjectivity proof is not watertight at all since you've just assumed what you should prove. You are given only that z in 1,...,mn and you should be able to construct explicitly (find such i,j) that z  = (i-1)m+j. Hint. Try to use induction on z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me do a little change: instead of $\{1,2,...,n\},\{1,2,...,m\},\{1,2,...,nm\}$ I will use $\{0,1,...,n-1\},\{0,1,...,m-1\},\{0,1,...,nm-1\}$.

Now, to prove $k$ is bijective I will find the inverse of $k$: $k(x_i,y_j)=(i-1)m + j$, to isolate $i$ I will use the fact that $j<m$, first let's divide by $m$: $\frac{(i-1)m + j}m=i-1 + \frac jm$, now notice that $i-1$ is an integer and $\frac jm$ is a fraction, so if I use the floor function on this expression I will get rid from $j$:$\lfloor i-1 + \frac jm\rfloor=i-1$, now adding to this $1$ we get $$\left\lfloor\frac{k(x_i,y_j)}{m}\right\rfloor+1=i\implies f^{-1}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{k(x_i,y_j)}{m}\right\rfloor+1\right)=x_i$$

Now we can easily isolate the $j$: $k(x_i,y_j)=(i-1)m + j=\left(\left\lfloor\frac{k(x_i,y_j)}{m}\right\rfloor+1-1\right)m+j=\left\lfloor\frac{k(x_i,y_j)}{m}\right\rfloor m+j\\\implies j=k(x_i,y_j)-\left\lfloor\frac{k(x_i,y_j)}{m}\right\rfloor m$
With this we only left to do is to use the inverse of $g$:$$j=k(x_i,y_j)-\left\lfloor\frac{k(x_i,y_j)}{m}\right\rfloor m\implies g^{-1}\left(k(x_i,y_j)-\left\lfloor\frac{k(x_i,y_j)}{m}\right\rfloor m\right)=y_j$$

Combining those 2 we get $$k^{-1}(z)=\left(f^{-1}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{z}{m}\right\rfloor+1\right),g^{-1}\left(z-\left\lfloor\frac{z}{m}\right\rfloor m\right)\right)$$

Thus we can conclude that $k$ is bijective

---

Here is a different proof that use induction.

It is trivial that $X\times \{a\}$ is the same size as $\{0,1,...,n-1\}$

Assuming that $X\times Y$ is the same size $\{0,1,...,nm-1\}$ I'll show that $X\times (Y\cup \{a\})$ where $a\notin Y$ is the same size of $\{0,1,...,n(m+1)-1\}$:

Let's call $h$ the bijective from $X\times Y$ to $\{0,1,...,nm-1\}$, then set $k(x_i,y_j)=h(x_i,y_j)$ if $(x_i,y_j)\in X\times Y$ and $k(x_i,y_j)=nm-1+i$ elsewhere, try to show that $k$ is bijective from $X\times (Y\cup \{a\})$ to $\{0,1,...,n(m+1)-1\}$ and then you are done with the induction 
!

Comment: too strong, I'm pretty sure he is meant to only use naturals and induction

Comment: @famesyasd What do you mean by too strong? it is possible to use induction but why?

Comment: Well I mean I have seen this exercise in two books, and in both it was before integers, rationals etc so I assumed that he shouldn't use what you have used yet.

Comment: Hmm @famesyasd , I got this question in my first course in set theory and I use this function with the inverse to show it is bijective

Comment: @Hai , please comment here, if you want for me to add a proof using induction

Comment: @famesyasd I asked the OP if he wants using induction. What you said could be correct

Comment: Ah I hadn't really considered that I probably shouldn't use rationals in the proof since the course hasn't covered it yet. In that case induction is probably what I should use.

Comment: @Hai I added a way using induction!

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Holo Should the base case not be when Y has cardinality $0$?

Comment: @Hai it doesn't matter, both work(and both trivial, $X\times\emptyset=\emptyset$)

Answer (score 1):

So for your bijection $F$ (here what I wrote is actually your $F^{-1}$) $$\forall x\, x \in F^{-1} \iff x \in \{1,...,mn\} \times (A \times B) $$$$\ \wedge\, \exists a \in \{1,...,m\},\ b \in \{1,...,n\}\ $$$$x = (n * P(a) + b,\, (f(a),\,g(b)).$$

You would want to prove the following lemma:

$$\forall m,n \in N\ \forall x\, x \in \{1,..,mn\}\implies \exists a \in \{1,...m\}\,\exists b \in \{1,...n\}\ x = (n*P(a) + b)$$
and
$$\forall m,n \in N\ \forall x\, x \in \{1,..,mn\}\forall a,c \in \{1,...m\}\,\forall b,d \in \{1,...n\}\ $$$$x = (n*P(a) + b) \wedge x = (n * P(c) + d) \implies (a = c \wedge b = d).$$
This lemma is needed to prove that you have surjectivity (the first part) and injectivity (the second).

To rewrite the notation: We have $$\forall m,n, x\ \,x \in \{m,..,n\} \iff m \leq x \wedge x \leq n$$ where $$\forall a,b\ \, a \leq b \iff a,b \in N \wedge \exists c \in N\, b = a + c$$
also we have $$\forall a \in N\, a \neq 0 \implies S(P(a)) = a$$ where $S$ is effectively $\forall n \in N\,S(n) = n + 1$ and $P(n) = n - 1$ provided that $n \neq 0$

For example to take injectivity Suppose that $a \neq c$ (for example if $a < c$ then we have the following series of inequalities:
$$nP(a) + b <= nP(a) + n = n(P(a) + 1) = n (P(a) + S(0)) = n (S(P(a)+0)) = n(S(P(a)) = n*a < n*a + 1 <= n*P(c) + 1 <= n*P(c) + d$$
Here you should be able to justify all transitions.

Answer (score 1):

Some context, perhaps of interest.

Want to find a bijection:

$f:${$ 0,1,2,.....,nm-1$} $\rightarrow X×Y$,

where  $X=${$0,1,2.....n-1$},  and

$Y=${$0,1,2,....m-1$}.

$X×Y=$ {$(i, k)|$
$0\le i \le n-1, 0 \le k \le m-1$}

In  matrix form

$(0,0) (0,1) (0,2).....(0,m-1)$

$(1,0) (1,1) (1,2).....(1,m-1)$

$ :$

$(n-1,0) (n-1,1)..(n-1,m-1)$.

Consider the dictionary order on the set $B:=X×Y$.

$A$ and $B$ have the same order type, if

there exists a bijection $f: A \rightarrow B$ s.t.

$a_1 <_A  a_2 \Rightarrow f(a_1) <f(a_2)$.

Let $k \in {0,1,2,....,mn-1}.$

Euclidean division :

$k= mq +r$, where $0 \le q$ , $0 \le r \lt m$,

with unique $q, r$.

$f: A \rightarrow B.$

$f(k) = f(mq+r) =(q, r)$.

$f$ is bijective.

(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division)